# Display HTML content in Silverlight without windowless=true

Tags: .net, silverlight, telerik

I'm new to Silverlight and want to display some **HTML** inside a **Silverlight App**. I've been reading about some ways to do it like the **HTMLPlaceHolder** from Telerik or **HTML Overlays** by mixing some css and javascript with the app.

The problem is that both require me to set the windowless=true which after going through its limitations on:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/11/12/limitations-of-windowless-mode-for-silverlight.aspx

I don't think will be worthily so, are there any ways to display **HTML without** the **windowless** set to true?

Thanks in advance for the assistance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the RadRichTextBox from Telerik which lets you render pretty much any type of document.

Herzmeister, thanks a lot for your answer, after looking at the code of the HTMLTextBlock you suggested I could come up with a solution.. here's the code I used..

> .xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="RadControlsSample.RadRichTextBoxTest"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"            
    xmlns:telerikHtml="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.Html;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.Html"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="700" d:DesignHeight="400" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Loaded="Example_Loaded">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <telerik:RadRichTextBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="richTextBox" DataContext="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" ShowMergeFieldsHighlight="False" IsSpellCheckingEnabled="False" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

> .cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Resources;
using Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.Html;
using Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model;

namespace RadControlsSample
{
    public partial class RadRichTextBoxTest : UserControl
    {
        private const string SampleDocumentPath = "SampleData/SomeHtml.html";

        public RadRichTextBoxTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Example_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Load html file from the content file
            var fileUri = new Uri(SampleDocumentPath, UriKind.Relative);
            StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(fileUri);
            var reader = new StreamReader(streamInfo.Stream);
            this.richTextBox.Document = new HtmlFormatProvider().Import(reader.ReadToEnd());
            this.richTextBox.Document.LayoutMode = DocumentLayoutMode.Flow;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Silverlight 4, there is a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) control that you can use when your application is running out of browser. Since Silverlight 5, it also works in the browser, but requires [elevated trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on the user's system.

For very simple HTML you can also try the [HtmlTextBlock](http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2010/09/15/Displaying-HTML-in-Silverlight.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I'm trying with the HtmlTextBlock but it's kind of strict you know.. I missed a closing tag and it raised an error.. that's alright though ^_^ but now it's not recognizing the white space **&nbsp;**. Anyway I'm giving it a try cause I don't want to use the WebBrowser. I appreciate you help.. thanks..